# Getting IP address from User

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm hard-coding an ip address for testing purposes as shown below.

```
string country = GetCountryByIP("173.194.113.23");
```

Now here's my GetCountryByIP method where the ip address is thrown into:

```
    public string GetCountryByIP(string ipAddress)
    {
        string ipResponse = IPRequestHelper("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=(api key deleted for security purposes)&ip=", ipAddress);

        XmlDocument ipInfoXML = new XmlDocument();
        ipInfoXML.LoadXml(ipResponse);
        XmlNodeList responseXML = ipInfoXML.GetElementsByTagName("Response");

        NameValueCollection dataXML = new NameValueCollection();

        dataXML.Add(responseXML.Item(0).ChildNodes[2].InnerText, responseXML.Item(0).ChildNodes[2].Value);

        string xmlValue = dataXML.Keys[0];

        return xmlValue;
    }
```

And my IP helper for response from api:

```
    public string IPRequestHelper(string url, string ipAddress)
    {
        string checkURL = url + ipAddress;

        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string responseRead = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        responseStream.Close();
        responseStream.Dispose();

        return responseRead;
    }
```

I get the response from the api in the xml saying it's an invalid ip address. In debug mode, the url and ip address is properly being passed into the parameters in both methods. I test the proper url and ip address in the address bar on my browser (hard-coding it) and it works properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, sorry guys. Where it is written:

```
    string checkURL = url + ipAddress;

    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

The issue was this:

```
    HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(checkUrl);
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```